# How to host a newportal instance in liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have created a new portal instance in liferay. I want to host it in my local Ubuntu machine.
What i have done is created a WEB ID as

> newportal.com

Virtual host as

> www.newportal.com

and the mail domain as

> newportal.com

thanks

Comment: What is the question again? I see what you have done, and it sounds OK, but what is the problem?

Comment: @Nenotlep as i have created a new instance newportal.com i want to run it over my system.

Comment: But what is the problem? Does liferay not start? Does your screen melt when accessing the site? Do you get a 404? 500? Some other site? Do you have DNS problems?

Comment: Please collect some karma by crossreferencing all the places on the web where you asked the same question. If someone has answered the question there already, we can save the same work at all of the other places.

Comment: @OlafKock I have posted the question on both sites at the same time.

Comment: I know - but you didn't link them to each other. So you're causing twice the effort as nobody knows that you've asked elsewhere and your question might already be answered in that other place. Bad style.

Comment: @OlafKock ok i will keep it in mind, actually i just asked the question and i left the place. Very thanks for your reply.

Comment: I was actually hoping that you retroactively add the link (in both directions). This will help those that come along later and might prefer a different explanation than the one that's given here, or there... sigh. https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/54221647

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add host file entry in `/etc/hosts` file to open `www.newportal.com` in your local browser.

For Example,

```
127.0.0.1 www.newportal.com
```

HTH